# Нажатие на элемент <div>

Tags: javascript, html

Сработает ли `.onclick = function(){` (js) при нажатии на элемент ? Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, просто не хочется потом переписывать очень большу́ю часть фронтенда.

Comment: Зачем извиняться за глупый вопрос, если его можно просто не задавать?

Comment: Удалить вопрос и все... Щас налетит 10 ответов))))

Comment: Да ладно вам, он с точкой написал, мало ли что он имел ввиду.

Comment: @Zicrael, А точка то тут при чем?)))

Comment: А кто его знает куда он её ставит)) вдруг в `html`.

Comment: Эм, можно же просто взять, сделать и попробовать нажать, не?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да сработает, при нажатии на любой элемент в принципе, разве что если на этот элемент зарегистрирован другой обработчик, тогда поведение вашего обработчика может быть непредсказуемо(не всегда).

Answer (score 0):

Сработает вот так:

```js
document.querySelector('div').onclick = function() {
  console.log('Я есть Div')
}
```

```html
<div> asd </div>
```